# Build a Regular Expression and Finite Automata

Tags: regex, automata

I need some help understanding how take the following to make a regular expression that will be used to generate an epsilon NFA.

Alphabet is {0,1}

Language is: The set of all strings beginning with 101 and ending with 01010.

Valid strings would be:

- 101010
- 10101010
- 101110101
- 1011101010

I am more concerned with understanding how to make the regular expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression you need is pretty simple:

```
101010|101(0|1)*01010 (theoretical)
```

or

```
^101010|101[01]*01010$ (used in most programming languages)
```

which means either:

- Match 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0

or

- Match 1, 0, and 1.
- Keep matching 0 or 1, zero or more times.
- Match 0, 1, 0, 1, 0.

The following non-deterministic automata should work:

[image]

Comment: The language isn't specified in the question but are you sure about the `(0+1)*` part? Why not `[01]*`?

Comment: @beroe I meant `|`, and I was using the syntax I learned in a compiler course a long time ago, which I believe is the *formal definition*, where `+` or `|` means an *union*. Of course, in most programming languages that would be expressed as `[01]*`, as you pointed out. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory

Comment: Looks good now. You might also want to anchor it with `^` and `$` at the beginning and end, since the current query would match `54321010101012345`

Comment: @beroe again, I'm referring to *theoretical* regular expressions, where that's not required, because when you create the automata, you specify an initial state `q_0` and a set of final states (in this example, only one state: `<q_8>`). I assumed the OP was talking about *theoretical* regular expressions when he mentioned the *alphabet*, *language*, *automata*, etc.

Comment: Hi. The theoretical stuff is over my head; I just operate in a practical world, but the unconstrained search term can also match incorrectly with only states 0,1 if it started with 111111...

Comment: @beroe If that's over your head, why do you say it will match incorrectly?. The string `111...` wouldn't be recognized by the automata. It would start in state `q_o` (the initial one), grab next character (`1`), then go to `q_1`. Now, the the next one is `1`, but it doesn't anywhere to go with `1`, so it wont' finish. It will only match the string if it ends in a final state (`q_8`) with no more characters to read (*i.e.* empty string remaining)

Comment: @Oscar, your pattern misses the case 101010.  The shortest string your pattern will match is 10101010.

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea of what you are looking for, it is helpful to use the intersection operator (denoted & below).  It does not belong to the core set of rational expressions, yet it preserves rationality --- in other words, you can use it, and always find a means to express the same language without it.

Using [Vcsn](http://vcsn-sandbox.lrde.epita.fr), I get this in text mode:

```
In [1]: import vcsn

In [2]: vcsn.B.expression('(101[01]*)&([01]*01010)').derived_term().expression()
Out[2]: 101010+101(0+1)*01010
```

and this in graphical mode, showing the intermediate automaton computed using `derived_term` (which includes details about the "meaning" of each state, so `strip` called afterwards to get something simpler to read):

[image: Graphical rendering of the automaton]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a pattern that includes both the base-case and general case.  You need to cover the base case of 101010, where the two patterns overlap (starts with "101", ends with "01010", and the last two digits of the first pattern are the first two digits of the second pattern.  Then you can cover the general case of "101", any 0s or 1s, "01010", as given by Oscar.

So the full pattern would be:

```
^(101010|(101[01]*01010))$
```